# What's going wrong with my Passenger on Apache2 (Sinatra) application?

Tags: ruby, apache2, sinatra, passenger

I have a LAMP stack deployed and functioning under www.mydomain.com as is, but when trying to deploy a Sinatra application (for a web API service) I'm not having any luck, despite having followed to the word several tutorials - should www.mydomain.com/api/services/test?id=test not be working with Sinatra deployed - just getting 403 errors. 'rackup' seems to suggest that it's listening on port 9292, but that doesn't seem to be showing any different. All of this was working on my local machine, but deploying to production hasn't worked in the slightest. Is the issue caused by the fact that Apache is already configured to listen on port 80 and direct them to my original site?

**Document Structure: (/var/www/sinatra)**

```
-app.rb
-library.rb
-config.ru
-public
-tmp
--restart.txt
```

**app.rb:**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'library.rb')

get '/api/services/test' do
    data = {:id => params[:id]}.to_json
end
```

**config.ru:**

```
require 'sinatra'
require File.expand_path '../app.rb', __FILE__

run Sinatra::Application
```

**Virtual Host:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sinatra/public
        <Directory /var/www/sinatra/public>
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```